# System.Diagnostics.Tracing Build Errors in Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to build a project in Mono (v4.4.1) that makes use of the System.Diagnostics.Tracing dll but I continually run into build errors:

```
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

Context/TplFrameworkListenerBase.cs(12,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `EventListener' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Context/TplFrameworkListenerBase.cs(52,40): error CS0115: `FastTrack.Context.TplFrameworkListenerBase.OnEventSourceCreated(System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
Context/TplFrameworkListenerBase.cs(114,55): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `EventWrittenEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Context/TplFrameworkListenerBase.cs(142,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `EventWrittenEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Context/TplFrameworkListenerBase.cs(147,69): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `EventWrittenEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I've tried also adding the nuget package as well as manually adding a reference to System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll and including the dll in the repo. When I manually add the reference it says I have two of the same references included in the project and won't build. Is there a way to get this working or are these properties just not implemented in the newest version of mono?

Comment: The System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource is specific for windows. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing(v=vs.110).aspx _The System.Diagnostics.Tracing namespace provides types and members that enable you to create strongly typed events to be captured by event tracing for Windows (ETW)._

Comment: It seems that there is an implementation of this in the mono repo: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/EventSource.cs unless I'm missunderstanding why that is there